# Shorthand for assigning variables

Tags: typescript

when I have this code

```
interface Foo1 {
    a: string;
    b: boolean
    c: Object;
}

interface Foo2 extends Foo1 {
    d: number;
}
```

can I use some shorthand for assigning variables from object created like `Foo1` to newly created object type `Foo2`?

This is a little bit annoying, when I have object with 10 attributes...

```
var test1: Foo1 = { a: '...', b: true, c: {} };

var test2: Foo2 = { a: test1.a, b: test1.b, c: test1.c, d: 3 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript will allow you to cast the item in this case... although this means that `test1` and `test2` are the same object.

```
interface Foo1 {
    a: string;
    b: boolean
    c: Object;
}

interface Foo2 extends Foo1 {
    d: number;
}

var test1: Foo1 = { a: '...', b: true, c: {} };

var test2: Foo2 = <Foo2> test1;
test2.d = 1;
```

If you want a copy, not the same object, you can create a method to copy the object's properties. Here is an example of a copy:

```
var test1: Foo1 = { a: '...', b: true, c: {} };

var test2: Foo2 = <Foo2>{};
for (var variable in test1) {
    if( test1.hasOwnProperty( variable ) ) {
        test2[variable] = test1[variable];
    }
}
```

With a little hint of generics, you can encapsulate this in a static helper method, like this:

```
class ObjectHelper {
    static copy<TFrom, TTo>(from: TFrom) : TTo {
        var to = <TTo> {};
        for (var variable in from) {
            if(from.hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
                to[variable] = from[variable];
            }
        }
        return to;
    }
}

var test1: Foo1 = { a: '...', b: true, c: {} };
var test2: Foo2 = ObjectHelper.copy<Foo1, Foo2>(test1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I will use your `ObjectHelper` ;-).